# Child booking through Expedia shown as adult on Malaysian airlines ticket?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, expedia, malaysia-airlines

I have booked one-way flights for my wife and 9-year-old daughter from Bangkok to London via KL on Malaysian Airlines through Expedia.

The Expedia confirmation shows the two travellers as one adult and one child, but the MAS ticket confirmation shows them as TWO adults. Will this be a problem when they check-in? How do I get the MAS confirmation changed to show one adult and one child as it's nigh on impossible to contact them?

Comment: Why would it be a problem?  The fare is usually the same for everyone 2 years old and older.  Is that not the case here?

Comment: Expedia plays some pricing games but one thing is they are reliable. Usually they charge a little less for the child ticket when you get the trip as multiple charges on your credit card you can see that, even though the fare is actually the same, I suspect maybe the taxes are not.

Comment: There was a small discount for the child, but that is not the problem. My concern is that a 9-year-old girl is shown as an ADULT on MAS eTicket and I am worried that there may be a problem when they check in. I have sent an email to Expedia about this but have not received a reply. Expedia's documentation shows her as a child but the airline shows her as an adult. Should I worry about this, as I won't be there?

Comment: @MobiDark Was there a issue in the checkin flight
as the same case with me, where my child (11 year) shown as adult in international travel by another airlines, although at time of booking was shown as child in online travel agency and discounted fare of child applies (been age is less than 12 yrs.)

Answer (score 5):

Nobody would care if the ticket lists your daughter as an adult. It might be a problem the other way around (adult listed as a child), but adult fares are always more expensive so the airline wouldn't care in the slighter.

Relax and enjoy your trip.